# Find exact duplicate records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

There are many questions about finding duplicates by a property, but I didn't find anything about finding exact matches.

I have the following (simplified) document structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId('...'),
    name: 'Some string',
    props: [
        {id: 100, val: 250},
        {id: 101, val: 350},
        {id: 102, val: 550},
        {id: 103, val: 150}
    ]
}
```

Currently I can find ids of documents with duplicated names using aggregation:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: { name: "$name" }, 
        uniqueIds: { $addToSet: "$_id" }, 
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}, 
    {$match: {
        count: { $gte: 2 } 
    }}
])
```

1) How can I find documents where the props arrays are also identical?

2) Is there a general way to find documents that are identical except their ObjectId?

Comment: how large is the props array,in general and does the order of objects inside the array matter ?

Comment: about 20 objects, and the order doesn't matter, but the id-val pairs should be the same